# How to batch add user's input to a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

Let's consider a situation when I ask user for input in Python and he copies the following words as an input:

```
Dog
Cat
Monkey
```

How do I convert his input to a list:

```
["Dog", "Cat", "Monkey"]
```

The words are entered simultaneously, **not one by one**.

BONUS QUESTION:
I need to consider a situation when the phrase I want to add as a single string consist of several words e.g. if the user's input is:

```
a dog
an apple
```

the list should be: `["a dog", "an apple"]` instead of `["a", "dog", "an", "apple"]`. Any good ideas how to do that?

Comment: Sounds like homework assignment.
What have you tried yet?

Comment: @Apero but you've missed the bonus round!

Comment: And how you are getting input from user ?

Comment: How are you going to decide where the first phrase ends and the second begins?

Comment: If they are on separate lines they _are_ one by one as far as `raw_input()` is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines). So given a string `example` (containing all the data) coming from STDIN, you could do:

```
_list = example.splitlines()
```

---

This works for both of the situations that you gave.